# change value of row and subsequent rows depending on row number

Tags: r

I have a dataframe where some rows have  values as 0. I want to make a code that makes the next few rows as 0 too.

```
> head(df$n,n=20)
              df$n
1                0
2             9009
3                0
4                0
5                0
6                0
7                0
8             5410
9                0
10               0
11               0
12               0
13               0
14               0
15              32
16               0
17               0
18            1054
19               0
20               0
```

I want to create a code that converts the next five rows with value 0 as 0.
basically row with 0 is 0 and the next five rows is also 0.

I tried

```
for(j in 1:nrow(indx)){
for(i in 1:4){
  df$n[j+i]<-0
}
}
```

where indx is dataframe containing all the row number with 0 values.

This works but incorrectly.

How to I get my desired output?

```
> head(df$n,n=20)
                  df$n
    1                0
    2                0
    3                0
    4                0
    5                0
    6                0
    7                0
    8             5410
    9                0
    10               0
    11               0
    12               0
    13               0
    14               0
    15              32
    16               0
    17               0
    18               0
    19               0
    20               0
```

Edit: sorry for the unclear language. My aim is to convert 5 values after 0 to 0. since it is incorrect data.

Edit2: I think this code worked for me. its a little bit primitive.

```
for( i in 1:nrow(indx)){
  u<-indx[i,]
  df[u,]<-0
  df[u+1,]<-0
  df[u+2,]<-0
  df[u+3,]<-0
  df[u+4,]<-0
  df[u+5,]<-0
}
```

however it introduces extra rows at end but it works.

Comment: What counts as a "new" zero? e.g., row 1 is zero, so rows 1 - 5 should all be zero, right? And row 9 is a zero coming right after a non-zero (5410), so rows 9 - 13 should all be zero, right? What about row 3? This comes right after a non-zero (9009), but this non-zero ends up getting removed; so does row 3 count as starting a new run of zeros, or is it just part of the run starting at row 1? It might help make it clearer if you add about the context / what this is for.

Comment: To make the question more concrete, what would the output be for `c(0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1)`? Would it be `c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1)` or `c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)`?

Comment: @zephryl the second. simply any row with 0 value should have the next 5 rows also 0. So second

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want to make sure any run of zeros is at least five rows long, unless it's at the end of the data. Here's a dplyr-based solution:

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  group_by(zero_run = cumsum(n == 0 & lag(n, default = 1) != 0)) %>% 
  mutate(
    zeros_consecutive = row_number(),
    n_new = ifelse(zero_run == 0 | zeros_consecutive > 5, n, 0)
  ) %>% 
  ungroup()
```

```
# # A tibble: 20 × 4
#       n zero_run zeros_consecutive n_new
#   <dbl>    <int>             <int> <dbl>
#  1     0        1                 1     0
#  2  9009        1                 2     0
#  3     0        2                 1     0
#  4     0        2                 2     0
#  5     0        2                 3     0
#  6     0        2                 4     0
#  7     0        2                 5     0
#  8  5410        2                 6  5410
#  9     0        3                 1     0
# 10     0        3                 2     0
# 11     0        3                 3     0
# 12     0        3                 4     0
# 13     0        3                 5     0
# 14     0        3                 6     0
# 15    32        3                 7    32
# 16     0        4                 1     0
# 17     0        4                 2     0
# 18  1054        4                 3     0
# 19     0        5                 1     0
# 20     0        5                 2     0
```

I left in the helper columns to better demonstrate the approach, but you could remove these by using `n = ifelse(...)` instead of `n_new = ifelse(...)` and adding `select(!zeros_run:zeros_consecutive)`.